# Converting a dataframe to KEGGGraph

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to convert a data frame into a KEGGGraph object. My data frame contains the intersection of two pathways and I want to graph it (var 16 in the code below)

```
retrieveKGML(pathwayid='05014', organism='hsa', destfile='hsa05014')
var12 <- system.file("extdata/hsa00020.xml",package="KEGGgraph")
var13 <- parseKGML2DataFrame(var12, reactions=FALSE)
var14 <- system.file("extdata/hsa05014.xml",package="KEGGgraph")
var15 <- parseKGML2DataFrame(var14, reactions=FALSE)
var16 <- intersect(var13, var15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for the file that makes `var14` in the wrong directory and instead you can just load the file you recently downloaded:

```
library(KEGGgraph)
retrieveKGML(pathwayid='05014', organism='hsa', destfile='hsa05014')
var12 <- system.file("extdata/hsa00020.xml",package="KEGGgraph")
var13 <- parseKGML2DataFrame(var12, reactions=FALSE)

var15 <- parseKGML2DataFrame("hsa05014", reactions=FALSE)
```

Also, I think you want `merge` and not `intersect`

```
var16 <- merge(var13, var15)
```

However this yields a `data.frame` with zero results which makes me think that possibly these sequences never overlapped in the first place.